# Simple histogram of two variables with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` to do an histogram for two weight variables in my dataframe. The dataframe has two columns, a column with case name `caso` and a value column named `peso`. I have 3000 cases for each, and when I put the histograms side by side with `facet_wrap`option they show correctly:

```
df |>
    pivot_longer(cols = c(peso,peso2), names_to = "caso", values_to = "peso") |>
    ggplot(aes(x = peso, colour= caso,  fill = caso))+
      geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4) +
      facet_wrap(~caso)
```

[image: facet_wrap]

But when I try to overlap the two histograms on the same frame, the first one seems to have double cases number, the histograms are unequal in size:

```
df |>
    pivot_longer(cols = c(peso,peso2), names_to = "caso", values_to = "peso") |>
    ggplot(aes(x = peso, colour= caso,  fill = caso))+
      geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Juan

Comment: By default `geom_histogram()` uses `position = "stack"` and so *stacks* the two groups. Try switching to `position = "identity"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default of `geom_histogram` is to stack multiple series. The "identity" position scheme should fix this:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df <- data.frame(peso = rnorm(1000, 250, 10),
                     peso2 = rnorm(1000, 260, 10))
    
    df %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
      geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
      # geom_histogram(position = position_identity(), alpha = 0.5) # alternate syntax
```

[image]

From the help for `?geom_histogram`, it looks like the "Usage" section shows that as the default. FWIW, `geom_freqpoly` defaults to "identity."

```
geom_histogram(
  mapping = NULL,
  data = NULL,
  stat = "bin",
  position = "stack",   #### HERE
  ...,
  binwidth = NULL,
  bins = NULL,
  na.rm = FALSE,
  orientation = NA,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, fixed it!

Comment: BTW, a bit overwhelmed by having an answer from the Director of FP&A at San Francisco Museum of Modern Ar!

Comment: Ha! Mola mazo tronco.